# How does OS X find/register Services automatically (from the mere presence of a .app in non-system folders)?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to understand how Mac OS (Mountain Lion, but I think since at least Leopard) automatically registers Services provided by applications (.app) that are present in archives but not installed to /Applications.  I have been googling for this but I am unable to find the underlying Mac OS "technology" responsible for this behavior (base search terms "services", "automatic", "mac os x" are not sufficiently specific to override general reading material).

Specifically, I am reinstalling from a Time Machine Backup and I noticed that Mac OS is automatically registering services for Applications that have not been installed (but are present in various archive folders).

Normally, I would expect that files I leave in non-system folders are not touched by the operating system, but clearly that is not the case here.  Of course, Spotlight indexes everything (in ~ anyway), but does it also register "interesting" files for system use?

I just want to understand this behavior and would appreciate any links or references.

Comment: Continuing to search yielded my own SO question...

Comment: [This page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-98828) implies that services must be installed to /Applications or /Library/Services to be registered automatically.

But [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/menu.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000851-BBCDFIDD) says "Applications that provide services may be installed anywhere on the system".

Does the user have any control over "OS X populat[ing] the items in the Services menu"?

Comment: The user can turn services on or off in the Keyboard prefpane.